# How to drag/drop component to another unknown form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I was wondering is it possible to drag and drop 1 component to another form without knowing which form I will drop to ?

For example : I have 10 different forms(form1-10), and I have a TPanel in form1. Lets say if I drag and drop the TPanel to form5, it will show caption like 'Panel is located in form5', if drop to form8 then 'Panel is located in form8', same goes to every forms.

There is no way I can hard code all forms in uses clause since I cannot predict how many forms will people open in real time. Please let me know if you have the answer.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No need to hard code anything. Just find traverse the parent relationship until you find the form and then get its name

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Wouldn't it be better to retrieve such information from OnDrop event that is fired within the scope of target form/control?

Comment: @SilverWarior You think that the `OnDrop` event has arguments that contain all of that information? Including both form names?

Comment: Look at the VCL's [`GetParentForm()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.GetParentForm) function. Pass it any `TControl` (like the `TPanel`) and it will return the `TForm` that the control is currently on.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what does 'find traverse the parent relationship' mean, and how to do it?

Comment: The function that Remy mentions does this.